# Chrome prerender: how to defer a javascript until page is actually loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using Chrome page prerendering:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="nextpage.html">
```

My problem is that on nextpage.html I have a javascript (notify.js) that displays a notification popup for a few seconds. Because the javascript is prerendered, users never actually see the notification (it's displayed in the hidden prerendered tab).

Is there a way that I can signal that a particular javascript is only executed on actual page display rather than on page pre-rendered? Looking at the Chrome [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/prerender) I see something about "plugin deferral" but no clear instructions as to javascript.

Comment: It seems like the page visibility api mentioned in the docs is what you want.

Comment: Incidentally, you'd have this problem without pre-render if a user reaches the page with the notification without displaying like with a 'open in new tab and don't foreground' command. One less-fancy solution is to not show invisible, auto-disappearing notifications but ones that the user can dismiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can postpone notification functionality until page becomes visible with [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

So basically try to subscribe to [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) event and fire necessary action when it becomes visible. Maybe you will need additional flag to notify only once:

```
let alreadyNotified = false

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (!document.hidden && !alreadyNotified) {
    // run notification
    alreadyNotified = true
  }
})
```